# Unable to set circle border on dots in imageslider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used slideshow from codepen https://codepen.io/dfitzy/pen/xZqGVo but i am unable to change these dots to change slides. I want to add black border around dot. When i try it it makes rectangle. To save your time this is class with dots "a.slide_btn".
I know its something little but i am unable to figure what.

```js
$('.slider').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $group = $this.find('.slide_group');
  var $slides = $this.find('.slide');
  var bulletArray = [];
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var timeout;
  
  function move(newIndex) {
    var animateLeft, slideLeft;
    
    advance();
    
    if ($group.is(':animated') || currentIndex === newIndex) {
      return;
    }
    
    bulletArray[currentIndex].removeClass('active');
    bulletArray[newIndex].addClass('active');
    
    if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
      slideLeft = '100%';
      animateLeft = '-100%';
    } else {
      slideLeft = '-100%';
      animateLeft = '100%';
    }
    
    $slides.eq(newIndex).css({
      display: 'block',
      left: slideLeft
    });
    $group.animate({
      left: animateLeft
    }, function() {
      $slides.eq(currentIndex).css({
        display: 'none'
      });
      $slides.eq(newIndex).css({
        left: 0
      });
      $group.css({
        left: 0
      });
      currentIndex = newIndex;
    });
  }
  
  function advance() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1)) {
        move(currentIndex + 1);
      } else {
        move(0);
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
  
  $('.next_btn').on('click', function() {
    if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1)) {
      move(currentIndex + 1);
    } else {
      move(0);
    }
  });
  
  $('.previous_btn').on('click', function() {
    if (currentIndex !== 0) {
      move(currentIndex - 1);
    } else {
      move(3);
    }
  });
  
  $.each($slides, function(index) {
    var $button = $('<a class="slide_btn">&bull;</a>');
    
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      $button.addClass('active');
    }
    $button.on('click', function() {
      move(index);
    }).appendTo('.slide_buttons');
    bulletArray.push($button);
  });
  
  advance();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #F7F5E6;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.slide_viewer {
  height:100%;
  height: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slide_group {
  
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide:first-child {
  height:100%;
  display: block;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  height:100%;
  background: #D7A151;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  height:100%;
  background: #F4E4CD;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #C75534;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  height:100%;
  background: #D1D1D4;
}

.slide_buttons {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

a.slide_btn {
  color: #474544;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 0 0.175em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slide_btn.active, .slide_btn:hover {
  color: #428CC6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.directional_nav {
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  position: relative;
  top: -340px;
}

.previous_btn {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.next_btn {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

.previous_btn, .next_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 65px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 65px;
}

.previous_btn:hover, .next_btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .previous_btn {
    left: 50px;
  }
  .next_btn {
    right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide_viewer">
    <div class="slide_group">
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- End // .slider -->

<div class="slide_buttons">
</div>
</div><!-- End // .directional_nav -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the circles used in there are symbols which is like letters. When you give border to `a.slide_btn` it just basically gives border to `a` which is container for letters(symbols). You have two ways actually, first way is drawing custom circles in svg format like the next and previous button used in slider. But if you want something simple you can just give text shadow to `a.slide_btn` which contains that circles.

```css
a.slide_btn {
  color: #428CC6;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
}
```

```html
<a class="slide_btn">•</a>
```